# How to safely convert a varchar(255) to an int?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I was using a column in a case expression and it was working fine on server1.  When I ran it on server2 it was failing because the column had the value 'false' in it.

The column is a varchar(255), but in my case expression I was using it as if it was an INT type.  It worked fine but now it is failing because of the 'false' value in server2.

How can I safely convert to an INT, and if the conversion fails, default to 0.

Is this possible?

My query looks like:

```
UPDATE t1
     set 
          c1 = ISNULL(
                     (
                       SELECT CASE c2
                            WHEN 123 then 'hello'
                            WHEN 234 then 'bye'
                            ELSE ''
                       END
                     )
                , '')
FROM table1 as t1
```

Comment: Hmmm... your `SELECT CASE` statement does't follow proper syntax. You need to remove the `SELECT` and either add an expression after `CASE` (before  `WHEN`) or replace you 123/234 by boolean expressions.

Comment: @JulienBlanchard I updated my post.  It works fine, just when the value of c2 is not numeric then the implicit cast is failing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are quite a few ways to convert from `numeric` to `varchar`, but none of them are available to you (really, SQLServer2008 is disappointing because it's lacking just a few cool features that are nearly required).

In your case, the best way to do is it simply to convert your numeric expression to varchar like this :

```
UPDATE t1
     set c1 = CASE c2
         WHEN '123' then 'hello'
         WHEN '234' then 'bye'
         ELSE ''
     END      
FROM @t1 t1
```

It doesn't answer the question, but it solves your problem.

Comment: I'm converting from varchar to INT

Comment: I know you are trying to convert from `varchar` to `numeric`, but it's far from foolproof in SQL2008, which is why I suggest that you do the opposite and compare them as `varchar`. Given your example, converting to `numeric` is simply a mistake. In fact, there are very few reasons to convert to `numeric` outside of arithmetical manipulations (`+`, `-`, `*`, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

Use `TRY_PARSE` (`SQL Server 2012+`):

```
SELECT ISNULL(TRY_PARSE(column_name AS INT),0)
FROM your_table;
```

**[LiveDemo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/398137)**

Comment: Using isnumeric can still cause problems, for example '-' is numeric according to it

Comment: looks like I don't have 2012, says function doesn't exist.

Comment: @JamesZ It is not problem, `SELECT CAST('-' AS INT); -- 0`

Comment: I updated my quesiton to show you how my case looks now.

Comment: @lad2025 isnumeric is flawed though since `1.45e99` is numeric but doesn't fit inside an int and causes an overflow.

Comment: And '£' is another example.